# Xpages: css for Form Table and Form Layout Row

Tags: css, xpages

I am still struggling with using a bit of css to modify my Xpages controls.

I have a Form Table with 2 form rows inside. I want to make the alignment a little better, by pushing elements to the left so they are only 5px from the border. I want some more space between each row.

I was able to use some css to get what I want in Safari, but it doesn't work in XPiNC, and I think the css is hacky. I use firebug and I use the web development tool in Safari but it still seems it is a lot of guesswork.

Here is what I want my form to look like:

[image]

Here is what I see in XPiNC:

[image]

Here is the Xpage and the css:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/frmTable.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:div
        style="width:60%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:25.0px;margin-bottom:auto">
        <xp:panel>
            <xe:formTable id="formTable1" formTitle="OTM Help Ticket">
                <xe:formRow id="formRow1" label="Status"
                    labelPosition="above">
                    <xe:djTextBox value="#{document1.status}"
                        id="status1" style="width:300px">
                        <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                            <xp:dojoAttribute name="readOnly"
                                value="true" />
                        </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                        <xe:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Name("[CN]",session.getEffectiveUserName())}]]></xe:this.defaultValue>
                    </xe:djTextBox>
                </xe:formRow>
                <xe:formRow id="formRow2" labelPosition="above"
                    label="Requester" style=".frmTable">
                    <xe:djTextBox value="#{document1.requestor}"
                        id="requestor1" style="width:300px">
                        <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                            <xp:dojoAttribute name="readOnly"
                                value="true" />
                        </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                        <xe:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Name("[CN]",session.getEffectiveUserName())}]]></xe:this.defaultValue>
                    </xe:djTextBox>
                </xe:formRow>

            </xe:formTable>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:div>

    </xp:view>




tr.lotusFormField >td {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

div.lotusFormLabel{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;   
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;

    }

tr.lotusFormFieldRow  > td{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
}
tr.lotusFormFieldRow > td
{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
}

div {
padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.lotusFormTitle 
{
  padding-left: 5px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css works in XPiNC too. My guess is that your changes don't take effect because of local cache.

Press **Ctrl+Shift+Delete** in XPiNC client, answer question "Delete all private data permanently" with "OK" and reload the XPage.